# Show div by calling php function with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a link, which brings other information according to the combine value. When I click on this link, I want to show the values ​​by opening a div on the same page with ajax.
Link :

```html
<a class="dropdown-item text-muted" href="index.php?module=events&action=generated&combine=<?php echo $C->combine ?>"><?= $L['btnDelete']; ?></a>
```

waiting for solution please

Comment: I think your approach is possible. However, normally you would use the URL as part of the Ajax request. For example `fetch(index.php?module=event....)`. You could trigger the fetch() / Ajax request by adding an event listener to the click event of a button or even an anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function like this to make the request and display the result:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
    fetch("index.php?module=events&action=generated&combine=<?php echo $C->combine ?>><?= $L['btnDelete'] ?>")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(body => console.log(body))
}
```

Then you could add an event listener to a button to trigger the request:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ajaxRequest();
}
```

In the ajaxRequest() function I have used the .json() method of the response object (`response.json()`). For that to work your PHP script at the URL provided as the argument to the fetch() function would need to echo a JSON string. You could achieve that with `echo json_encode($myArray)`. The query parameters will be available to your PHP script as `$_GET['module'] etc.